# Difference between extension and direct call for protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

I got this code:

```
protocol Protocol {
    var id: Int { get }
}

extension Array where Element: Protocol {
    func contains(_protocol: Protocol) -> Bool {
        return contains(where: { $0.id == _protocol.id })
    }
}

class Class {
    func method<T: Protocol>(_protocol: T) {
        var arr = [Protocol]()

        // Does compile
        let contains = arr.contains(where: { $0.id == _protocol.id })

        // Doens't compile
        arr.contains(_protocol: _protocol)
    }
}
```

Why doesn't the line of code compile where I commented 'Doens't compile'? This is the error:

```
Incorrect argument label in call (have '_protocol:', expected 'where:')
```

When I change the method name in the extension to something else, like `containz` (and ofcourse change the name of the method that calls it to `containz`), I get this error when I try to call it:

```
Using 'Protocol' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'Protocol' is not supported
```

But why doesn't it work when I try to call it through an extension, but it does work when I create the function in the extension directly? There isn't really any difference that I can see.

Comment: Ultimately a probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with matt that the underlying answer is [Protocol doesn't conform to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself), but it's probably worth answering anyway, since in this case the answer is very simple. First, read the linked question about why `[Protocol]` doesn't work the way you think it does (especially Hamish's answer, which is much more extensive than the accepted answer that I wrote). `[Protocol]` does not match the `where Element: Protocol` clause because `Protocol` is not a concrete type that conforms to `Protocol` (because it's not a concrete type).

But you don't need `[Protocol]` here. You have `T: Protocol`, so you can (and should) just use that:

```
var arr = [T]()
```

With that change, the rest should work as you expect because `T` is a concrete type that conforms to Protocol.